# IntelliJ runClient won't work minecraft forge

Tags: java, intellij-idea, minecraft

I just ported my Minecraft mod to version `1.16.1`. When I am trying to run the game to see if it worked, it says Process finished with exit code 1.

Below is the sack trace from runClient:

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/jhausam/.var/app/com.jetbrains.IntelliJ-IDEA-Community/cache/tmp/
[10:41:32] [main/INFO] [cp.mo.mo.Launcher/MODLAUNCHER]: ModLauncher running: args [--gameDir, ., --launchTarget, fmluserdevclient, --fml.mcpVersion, 20200625.160719, --fml.mcVersion, 1.16.1, --fml.forgeGroup, net.minecraftforge, --fml.forgeVersion, 32.0.63, --version, MOD_DEV, --assetIndex, 1.16, --assetsDir, /home/jhausam/.gradle/caches/forge_gradle/assets, --username, Dev, --accessToken, ❄❄❄❄❄❄❄❄, --userProperties, {}]
[10:41:32] [main/INFO] [cp.mo.mo.Launcher/MODLAUNCHER]: ModLauncher 5.1.0+69+master.79f13f7 starting: java version 1.8.0_101 by Oracle Corporation
[10:41:32] [main/DEBUG] [cp.mo.mo.LaunchServiceHandler/MODLAUNCHER]: Found launch services [minecraft,fmldevdata,fmldevclient,fmldevserver,fmluserdevserver,testharness,fmluserdevdata,fmlclient,fmluserdevclient,fmlserver]
[10:41:32] [main/DEBUG] [cp.mo.mo.NameMappingServiceHandler/MODLAUNCHER]: Found naming services : [srgtomcp]
[10:41:32] [main/DEBUG] [cp.mo.mo.LaunchPluginHandler/MODLAUNCHER]: Found launch plugins: [eventbus,object_holder_definalize,runtime_enum_extender,accesstransformer,capability_inject_definalize,runtimedistcleaner]
[10:41:32] [main/DEBUG] [cp.mo.mo.TransformationServicesHandler/MODLAUNCHER]: Discovering transformation services
[10:41:32] [main/DEBUG] [cp.mo.mo.TransformationServicesHandler/MODLAUNCHER]: Found additional transformation services from discovery services: []
[10:41:32] [main/DEBUG] [cp.mo.mo.TransformationServicesHandler/MODLAUNCHER]: Found transformer services : [fml]
[10:41:32] [main/DEBUG] [cp.mo.mo.TransformationServicesHandler/MODLAUNCHER]: Transformation services loading
[10:41:32] [main/DEBUG] [cp.mo.mo.TransformationServiceDecorator/MODLAUNCHER]: Loading service fml
[10:41:32] [main/DEBUG] [ne.mi.fm.lo.FMLServiceProvider/]: Injecting tracing printstreams for STDOUT/STDERR.
[10:41:32] [main/DEBUG] [ne.mi.fm.lo.LauncherVersion/CORE]: Found FMLLauncher version 32.0
[10:41:32] [main/DEBUG] [ne.mi.fm.lo.FMLLoader/CORE]: FML 32.0 loading
[10:41:32] [main/DEBUG] [ne.mi.fm.lo.FMLLoader/CORE]: FML found ModLauncher version : 5.1.0+69+master.79f13f7
[10:41:32] [main/DEBUG] [ne.mi.fm.lo.FMLLoader/CORE]: Initializing modjar URL handler
[10:41:32] [main/DEBUG] [ne.mi.fm.lo.FMLLoader/CORE]: FML found AccessTransformer version : 2.1.3+56+master.cd48380
[10:41:32] [main/DEBUG] [ne.mi.fm.lo.FMLLoader/CORE]: FML found EventBus version : 2.2.0+59+master.4f71e48
[10:41:32] [main/DEBUG] [ne.mi.fm.lo.FMLLoader/CORE]: Found Runtime Dist Cleaner
[10:41:32] [main/DEBUG] [ne.mi.fm.lo.FMLLoader/CORE]: FML found CoreMod version : 2.0.3+8+master.ca72757
[10:41:32] [main/DEBUG] [ne.mi.fm.lo.FMLLoader/CORE]: Found ForgeSPI package implementation version 3.0.0+10+master.d73b00c
[10:41:32] [main/DEBUG] [ne.mi.fm.lo.FMLLoader/CORE]: Found ForgeSPI package specification 3
[10:41:32] [main/INFO] [ne.mi.fm.lo.FixSSL/CORE]: Added Lets Encrypt root certificates as additional trust
[10:41:32] [main/DEBUG] [cp.mo.mo.TransformationServiceDecorator/MODLAUNCHER]: Loaded service fml
[10:41:32] [main/DEBUG] [cp.mo.mo.TransformationServicesHandler/MODLAUNCHER]: Configuring option handling for services
[10:41:32] [main/DEBUG] [cp.mo.mo.TransformationServicesHandler/MODLAUNCHER]: Transformation services initializing
[10:41:32] [main/DEBUG] [cp.mo.mo.TransformationServiceDecorator/MODLAUNCHER]: Initializing transformation service fml
[10:41:32] [main/DEBUG] [ne.mi.fm.lo.FMLServiceProvider/CORE]: Setting up basic FML game directories
[10:41:32] [main/DEBUG] [ne.mi.fm.lo.FileUtils/CORE]: Found existing GAMEDIR directory : /home/jhausam/MC modding/Test/run
[10:41:32] [main/DEBUG] [ne.mi.fm.lo.FMLPaths/CORE]: Path GAMEDIR is /home/jhausam/MC modding/Test/run
[10:41:32] [main/DEBUG] [ne.mi.fm.lo.FileUtils/CORE]: Found existing MODSDIR directory : /home/jhausam/MC modding/Test/run/mods
[10:41:32] [main/DEBUG] [ne.mi.fm.lo.FMLPaths/CORE]: Path MODSDIR is /home/jhausam/MC modding/Test/run/mods
[10:41:32] [main/DEBUG] [ne.mi.fm.lo.FileUtils/CORE]: Found existing CONFIGDIR directory : /home/jhausam/MC modding/Test/run/config
[10:41:32] [main/DEBUG] [ne.mi.fm.lo.FMLPaths/CORE]: Path CONFIGDIR is /home/jhausam/MC modding/Test/run/config
[10:41:32] [main/DEBUG] [ne.mi.fm.lo.FMLPaths/CORE]: Path FMLCONFIG is /home/jhausam/MC modding/Test/run/config/fml.toml
[10:41:32] [main/DEBUG] [ne.mi.fm.lo.FMLServiceProvider/CORE]: Loading configuration
[10:41:32] [main/DEBUG] [ne.mi.fm.lo.FileUtils/CORE]: Found existing default config directory directory : /home/jhausam/MC modding/Test/run/defaultconfigs
[10:41:32] [main/DEBUG] [ne.mi.fm.lo.FMLServiceProvider/CORE]: Preparing ModFile
[10:41:32] [main/DEBUG] [ne.mi.fm.lo.FMLServiceProvider/CORE]: Preparing launch handler
[10:41:32] [main/DEBUG] [ne.mi.fm.lo.FMLLoader/CORE]: Using fmluserdevclient as launch service
[LWJGL] GLFW_API_UNAVAILABLE error
                                                                                                                        [LWJGL] GLFW_FORMAT_UNAVAILABLE error
                                                                                                                        Exception in thread "main" [10:41:32] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWErrorCallback$1:invoke:105]:   Description : GLX: No GLXFBConfigs returned
[10:41:32] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWErrorCallback$1:invoke:106]:  Stacktrace  :
[10:41:32] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWErrorCallback$1:invoke:110]: org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.nglfwCreateWindow(GLFW.java:1714)
[10:41:32] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWErrorCallback$1:invoke:110]: org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.glfwCreateWindow(GLFW.java:1897)
[10:41:32] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWErrorCallback$1:invoke:110]: net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.progress.ClientVisualization.initWindow(ClientVisualization.java:84)
[10:41:32] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWErrorCallback$1:invoke:110]: net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.progress.ClientVisualization.start(ClientVisualization.java:287)
[10:41:32] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWErrorCallback$1:invoke:110]: net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.progress.EarlyProgressVisualization.accept(EarlyProgressVisualization.java:36)
[10:41:32] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWErrorCallback$1:invoke:110]: net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.FMLLoader.setupLaunchHandler(FMLLoader.java:186)
[10:41:32] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWErrorCallback$1:invoke:110]: net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.FMLServiceProvider.initialize(FMLServiceProvider.java:94)
[10:41:32] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWErrorCallback$1:invoke:110]: cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformationServiceDecorator.onInitialize(TransformationServiceDecorator.java:68)
[10:41:32] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWErrorCallback$1:invoke:110]: cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformationServicesHandler.lambda$initialiseTransformationServices$7(TransformationServicesHandler.java:107)
[10:41:32] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWErrorCallback$1:invoke:110]: java.util.HashMap$Values.forEach(HashMap.java:980)
[10:41:32] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWErrorCallback$1:invoke:110]: cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformationServicesHandler.initialiseTransformationServices(TransformationServicesHandler.java:107)
[10:41:32] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWErrorCallback$1:invoke:110]: cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformationServicesHandler.initializeTransformationServices(TransformationServicesHandler.java:59)
[10:41:32] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWErrorCallback$1:invoke:110]: cpw.mods.modlauncher.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:75)
[10:41:32] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWErrorCallback$1:invoke:110]: cpw.mods.modlauncher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:65)
[10:41:32] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWErrorCallback$1:invoke:110]: net.minecraftforge.userdev.LaunchTesting.main(LaunchTesting.java:105)
[10:41:32] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWErrorCallback$1:invoke:105]:  Description : GLX: Failed to find a suitable GLXFBConfig
[10:41:32] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWErrorCallback$1:invoke:106]:  Stacktrace  :
[10:41:32] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWErrorCallback$1:invoke:110]: org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.nglfwCreateWindow(GLFW.java:1714)
[10:41:32] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWErrorCallback$1:invoke:110]: org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.glfwCreateWindow(GLFW.java:1897)
[10:41:32] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWErrorCallback$1:invoke:110]: net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.progress.ClientVisualization.initWindow(ClientVisualization.java:84)
[10:41:32] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWErrorCallback$1:invoke:110]: net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.progress.ClientVisualization.start(ClientVisualization.java:287)
[10:41:32] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWErrorCallback$1:invoke:110]: net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.progress.EarlyProgressVisualization.accept(EarlyProgressVisualization.java:36)
[10:41:32] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWErrorCallback$1:invoke:110]: net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.FMLLoader.setupLaunchHandler(FMLLoader.java:186)
[10:41:32] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWErrorCallback$1:invoke:110]: net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.FMLServiceProvider.initialize(FMLServiceProvider.java:94)
[10:41:32] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWErrorCallback$1:invoke:110]: cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformationServiceDecorator.onInitialize(TransformationServiceDecorator.java:68)
[10:41:32] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWErrorCallback$1:invoke:110]: cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformationServicesHandler.lambda$initialiseTransformationServices$7(TransformationServicesHandler.java:107)
[10:41:32] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWErrorCallback$1:invoke:110]: java.util.HashMap$Values.forEach(HashMap.java:980)
[10:41:32] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWErrorCallback$1:invoke:110]: cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformationServicesHandler.initialiseTransformationServices(TransformationServicesHandler.java:107)
[10:41:32] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWErrorCallback$1:invoke:110]: cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformationServicesHandler.initializeTransformationServices(TransformationServicesHandler.java:59)
[10:41:32] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWErrorCallback$1:invoke:110]: cpw.mods.modlauncher.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:75)
[10:41:32] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWErrorCallback$1:invoke:110]: cpw.mods.modlauncher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:65)
[10:41:32] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWErrorCallback$1:invoke:110]: net.minecraftforge.userdev.LaunchTesting.main(LaunchTesting.java:105)
[10:41:32] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:1052]: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create the GLFW window
[10:41:32] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:1052]:   at net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.progress.ClientVisualization.initWindow(ClientVisualization.java:86)
[10:41:32] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:1052]:   at net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.progress.ClientVisualization.start(ClientVisualization.java:287)
[10:41:32] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:1052]:   at net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.progress.EarlyProgressVisualization.accept(EarlyProgressVisualization.java:36)
[10:41:32] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:1052]:   at net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.FMLLoader.setupLaunchHandler(FMLLoader.java:186)
[10:41:32] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:1052]:   at net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.FMLServiceProvider.initialize(FMLServiceProvider.java:94)
[10:41:32] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:1052]:   at cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformationServiceDecorator.onInitialize(TransformationServiceDecorator.java:68)
[10:41:32] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:1052]:   at cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformationServicesHandler.lambda$initialiseTransformationServices$7(TransformationServicesHandler.java:107)
[10:41:32] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:1052]:   at java.util.HashMap$Values.forEach(HashMap.java:980)
[10:41:32] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:1052]:   at cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformationServicesHandler.initialiseTransformationServices(TransformationServicesHandler.java:107)
[10:41:32] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:1052]:   at cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformationServicesHandler.initializeTransformationServices(TransformationServicesHandler.java:59)
[10:41:32] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:1052]:   at cpw.mods.modlauncher.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:75)
[10:41:32] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:1052]:   at cpw.mods.modlauncher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:65)
[10:41:32] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:1052]:   at net.minecraftforge.userdev.LaunchTesting.main(LaunchTesting.java:105)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Does `./gradlew runClient` work in a fresh Forge MDK instance, with none of your own code?

Comment: idk. how would I test that? sorry I'm a noob.

Answer (score 0):

try restarting the launcher then the device.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please, [edit] and try for [answer], describe the effect of what you propose and explain why it helps to solve the problem. You can e.g. phrase a conditional answer like "If your problem is ... then the solution is ... because ... ." Consider taking the [tour].